# Android SQLite rawQuery with WHERE clause returns search string as column not found

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have created a table called CHEMISTID:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_CHEMISTID = "CREATE TABLE "
        + CHEMISTID + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + KEY_CHEMISTID
        + " TEXT" + ")";
```

My insert function works properly but when I run a search query to find if a chemistId is already present using the following query statement:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + CHEMISTID +" WHERE " + KEY_CHEMISTID + " = "+ chemistID + ";";

Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);
```

My logcat displays the following error message:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(1169): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(1169): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Spain (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT  * FROM chemistIdTable WHERE chemistId = Spain;
```

Where Spain is a particular chemistId that I have dynamically created in my program.

How should I fix my selectQuery String so that it searches in the column name KEY_CHEMISTID for a particular String chemistId?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to quote your strings such as `Spain` in SQL so they get taken as string literals and not column name identifiers. You can use single quotes like `'Spain'` for that.

However it's much better to use `?` parameter placeholders instead and supply the parameter values in the selection args array, like:

```
 ... KEY_CHEMISTID + "=?" ...

c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[] { chemistID });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for not only showing me the correct answer but also making me understanding the logic behind it. In order to implement the same logic to a complex query with subqueries, should I split it into different queries strings?
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + DATE + " WHERE " + KEY_ID + " = '(SELECT " + KEY_DATE_ID 
          + " FROM " + CHEMISTID_DATE_ORDERNUMBER_ORDERDATA +
               " WHERE " + KEY_CHEMISTID_ID + " = '(SELECT " + KEY_ID + " FROM " + CHEMISTID + " WHERE " + KEY_CHEMISTID + " = " + chemistId +")')' AND " + KEY_DATE + " = ' " + date + " ' ";

Comment: You can have more than one `?` in the query string. Just supply the equal amount of values in the selection args array.

Comment: Would this be the correct solution?

 `String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + DATE + " WHERE " + KEY_ID + " = (SELECT " + KEY_DATE_ID + " FROM " + CHEMISTID_DATE_ORDERNUMBER_ORDERDATA + " WHERE " + KEY_CHEMISTID_ID + " = (SELECT " + KEY_ID + " FROM " + CHEMISTID + " WHERE " + KEY_CHEMISTID + " =? "+")) AND " + KEY_DATE + " =?";
     
        Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);
     
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[] { chemistId,date});`

Answer (score 1):

You missed single quote,So change

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + CHEMISTID +" WHERE " + KEY_CHEMISTID + " = "+ chemistID + ";";
```

to

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + CHEMISTID +" WHERE " + KEY_CHEMISTID + " = '"+ chemistID + "';";
```

Recommended solution is to use **parameterized query** as

```
Cursor c = db.query(CHEMISTID, null, KEY_CHEMISTID + "=?",
            new String[] { chemistID  },null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution! I realised the error and it works now. But if I use a parameterized query and if one of the parameter fails it would crash my enter application. Later in my application I am also using several complex subqueries which would not be ideal to use in a parameterized query